# Dead ASUS laptop - Can I boot Windows from within Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, hard-drive, asus, bios

I have an ASUS laptop (model u56e, windows 7 64-bit) that is baffling me right now.  I was recently on a trip, laptop working fine, though partitioned SATA HDD a bit overloaded with vacay pics. On way home, closed my laptop, put it in bag & didn't open it again for 2 days.  When I did it was dead - POST audio, but stuck on ASUS splash screen.

What I have done so far:

1. Removed HDD
2. Booted into Ubuntu using DVD
3. Connected HDD with SATA/USB cable & backed up important files.  It would not mount OS partition, just data partition.  Gave me "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount" error.
4. Successfully mounted OS partition using remove_hiberfile command.
5. Reinstalled HDD. Still stuck on splash screen.
6. Removed/reset CMOS battery. No change.
7. Confirmed I have latest BIOS. Reset BIOS defaults. No change.

Current status:

```
*HDD appears healthy. Spins up, no strange noises, able to access/transfer files, etc.
*Only able to enter BIOS with HDD removed. As soon as I reinstall HDD, can no longer enter BIOS. 
*Unable to see if HDD is recognized in BIOS or not & obviously unable to change boot order. BIOS does recognize USB if I plug in flash drive.
```

I'm at a loss for what to do next. My questions are:

1. If the connector for the HDD is bad, wouldn't the BIOS just not recognize the drive & move on to boot from DVD?
2. Is there a way to boot into the Windows OS from within the Ubuntu terminal so that I may do a proper complete shutdown now that hiberfil.sys is gone? (I cannot find my original windows 7 CD)

Sorry for any ignorance. Just have reached the end of my limited knowledge.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Try telling grub to boot into windows on next boot: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57792

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything plugged in your computer? USB drives, SD cards, etc? I have heard of computers trying to boot to SD cards or USB sticks with nothing on them before. If you don't have anything wrong, see if you can find any windows 7 DVD (does a friend have one you could use?) and boot into the repair tools and command prompt to see if you can locate your hard drive from there, try doing check disk and sfc scans on the drive from there if possible, if you need more info on how to do that I can post more tomorrow.

I don't think there is a way you can boot into windows from within Linux, the only thing you can do there is a virtual windows machine in a Linux machine, but I don't think you can boot to a hard disk from within a live CD.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, I don't have anything connected, just tested a USB drive to see if the BIOS recognized it (it did). I'm going to try to locate a Windows disk & follow your advice.  Thanks for clarifying about booting from the live CD!

Comment: I'm thinking that if checkdisk and sfc scans don't find anything, maybe you can search online about repairing the bootloader in windows but if none of that works out, it would be safe to say that the hard drive is possibly bad. Next steps would be maybe contacting the manufacturer of the hard drive and seeing if they have tools to scan the drive for issues and possibly fix issues. I can't be 100% sure by just talking through the computer what it is, but just going through some of the troubleshooting steps I would do. (Sorry for the terrible run-ons)